# Apache individual DocumentRoot per REMOTE_USER

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, http-basic-authentication

How can I give authenticated users an individual view of the DocumentRoot?

I would like to lock users in their own directory. When *alice* visits `http://example.net/` she only sees `/srv/www/alice/` and *bob* sees `/srv/www/bob/`. I tried this:

```
DocumentRoot "/srv/www"
<Location />
    Require         valid-user
    AuthType        Basic
    AuthUserFile    /etc/apache2/passwd
    RewriteEngine   On
    RewriteRule     ^/(.*)$ /%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} [PT]
</Location>
```

But this way both users can access each others directory. Is it possible to configure Apache in a way that *alice* and *bob* are strictly separated?